# configure firebase with options is crashing in Xcode 11 and Firebase 6.19

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xcode11

I'm trying to register a second firebase application in my app. The first one is correctly registered inside `didFinishWithLaunchingWithOptions` method (by default is using the GoogleService-Info.plist)

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Then I need to retrieve a new googleAppId from a server and configure a new application using this new googleAppId and using my iOSID of curse. I am doing all this registration inside AppDelegate. I'm registering this way:

```
let options = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: String(format: "1:%a:ios:%a", googleID, iOSID), gcmSenderID: googleID)
//Deleting the first app in order to register the second
let app = FirebaseApp.app()
app?.delete { _ in }
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
```

It was working well until I update my firebase version from 6.2 to 6.19, now the app is crashing in `FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)`

The log says:

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.installations', reason
    '[Firebase/Installations][I-FIS008000] Could not confiure Firebase Installations die to invalid 
    Firebase options. The following parameters are nil or empty: `FirebaseOptions.APIKEY`. If you
    use GoogleServices-Info.plist please download the most recent version from the Firebase Console. 
    If you configure Firebase in code, please make sure you specify all required paramaters.
```

Is worth mencioning that a new Framework was added to Analytics in Firebase version 6.15 so I had to added it in order to make my app compile again.

I also tried to add a new parameter inside the `FirebaseOptions` but is still asking for the same parameters, it is not expecting an APIKEY which i don't know where to get it

Comment: From the error message it looks like you need to specify `APIKEY` in your `FirebaseOptions`, which your code isn't doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message comes from [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/1bc325543614a5a1723e9f9ccd6800f7233de081/FirebaseInstallations/Source/Library/FIRInstallations.m#L122-L152) as far as I can see. The check done there shows that these three values must always be specified:

> ```
>   if (appName.length < 1) {
>     [missingFields addObject:@"`FirebaseApp.name`"];
>   }
>   if (appOptions.APIKey.length < 1) {
>     [missingFields addObject:@"`FirebaseOptions.APIKey`"];
>   }
>   if (appOptions.googleAppID.length < 1) {
>     [missingFields addObject:@"`FirebaseOptions.googleAppID`"];
>   }
> ```

From the error message and your code it looks like you're not specifying the `APIKEY` in your FirebaseOptions, which is required according to the SDK.

Comment: You're right, all I had to do was specify an APIKEY and Project ID this way `options.APIKEY = "My api key"` and `options.projectID = "my project Id"`. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do that. Thank you again Frank